# Mail Compose View Controller won't dismiss when called from NSObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have several View Controllers that need to send emails, so to keep things Object-Oriented, I created an NSObject class called **MessagingObject** to handle these messages.  But I'm not sure how to dismiss the MailComposeVC since it's coming from a non-VC object.  The implementation looks like this:

```
//.m file
#import "MessagingObject.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface MessagingObject () <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end
@implementation MessagingObject


.....

#pragma mark - Email Messaging Methods

- (void)sendEmail:(NSString *)description withSubject:(NSString *)subj toRecipients:(NSArray *) recipients fromController:(id)sender{

    // Building the email content

     MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController     alloc] init];
     mc.mailComposeDelegate = sender; //Delegated to the sending VC so it could bring out the composer
    [mc setSubject:subj];
    [mc setMessageBody:description isHTML:YES];
    [mc setToRecipients:recipients];


    // Present mail view controller on screen from the sender VC
    [sender presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    //Check the result of the email being sent
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // Close the Mail Interface here, this won't work with *self* (which references the MessagingObject)
    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    //This delegate will notify the corresponding VC when the mail has been sent
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(messageDidSend)]) {
        [self.delegate messageDidSend];
    }
}
@end
```

Annd this is the method used to call the MessagingObject:

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {

    MessagingObject *aMessenger = [[MessagingObject alloc] init];
    aMessenger.delegate = self;

    NSString desc = @"A sample Description";        
    NSString subj = @"A sample subject";

    NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"recipient@gmail.com", nil];
    [aMessenger sendMail:desc withSubject:subj recipientList:recipients fromController:self];
}
```

I tried using a delegate called **MessengerDelegate** in my header file with the method **messageDidSend:** to notify the VC when to dismiss the MailComposeVC.  But for some reason, the **mailComposeController didFinishWithResult** is not being called, I think it has to do with how I delegated things.  Anyways, how could I dismiss the MailComposeVC?

Comment: Save `sender` in an instance variable. Then you can reference when you need to dismiss the mail composer.

Comment: Just tried that, but it won't get dismissed when I need it to, which is in the **mailComposeController didFinishWithResult** method.  For whatever reason, that method is being skipped.

Mind you, this code works fine when I call it straight from the View Controller.

Comment: When I set `mailComposeDelegate` to `self`, it crashes the app, before it even sends an email, so I can't tell if calling `dismiss...` on `controller` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Set the `mailComposeDelegate` to `self`, not `sender` since it is `self` that has the delegate method implemented.

   ```
   mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   ```
2. Call `dismiss...` on `controller` in the delegate method.

   ```
   [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   ```

Comment: When I set mailComposeDelegate to `self`, it crashes the app on the Mail Compose VC (let alone reach the `didFinishWithResult' method), so I can't tell if calling `dismiss...` on `controller` would work. Maybe I'm missing a delegate method implementation?

Comment: Actually, the problem is due to the fact that `aMessenger` goes out of scope at the end of your `sendEmail:` method. Instead of a local variable, use an instance variable.

Comment: There we go! Worked perfectly! You saved me a headache, thanks!